# NLog log file on Xamarin - Android issues

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, nlog

I have been trying to use NLog from android, and it works whilst using a console based output. However when i try to target an external storage area/file nothing happens....there is no log file created...

My manifest contains the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My Nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="storage\emulated\0\Download\log.txt" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

My activity MainActivity.cs :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Logger sm_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        sm_logger.Debug("test output");
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
```

All of this code runs, no errors seem to be thrown, however no file is created either...using the console logger does infact output to the console however... Any help would be appreciated.

Note:

Im using both the emulator and a device, neither have a log file created.

Im building for android 7.1 level 25 of api.

The NLog.config file is bundled as a androidasset, and seems to load as it can find the targets etc

Comment: What happens if you add a call to `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()`before application exit? Have you tried the NLog internal logger?

Comment: After testing LogManager.shutdown, it doesent seem to do annything still, likewise the internal logger also doesent create the file on my local C drive as i would expect when used form the android application...

Comment: Have you tried to enable the internal logger by code? Remember that by default then Xamerin Android Linker will strip anything not directly referenced (unless told otherwise). NLog works by reflection so is easily stripped to nothing.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, the logger is clearly working because I can see the messages in the VS Console window but no file gets created.  Happens the same on Android and Apple

Comment: After looking into it further i found that it seemed to create an internal logger, i.e it existsed within the app domain space but not physically on the disk. I eventually worked around this using serilog and providing my own write file implementation of the logger as a Sink, however im unsure why this is the normal behaviour of nlog.

Comment: Facing same issue, if anybody find propere steps to implement nLog for Xamarin.Android please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to have

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

you also need to request the persmission with something like

`ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Adapter.Activity, new String[] {  Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1234);`

(which is incomplete, you also need to handle the permission result, but there are good resources out there on how to do that).

This needs to happen **before** the NLog FileTarget is created.